# $e^{it}$ and $e^{2it}$ are not equivalent as curves.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, graphing-functions, equivalence-relations

I am not getting any clue to show that $t \to e^{it}$ and $t \to e^{2it}$ are not equivalent as curves. But we get the same picture when we draw but the speed by which we travel is 2 times in the second than the first. By equivalent we mean that there is a continuous bijection.

The map is from the set $[0,2\pi]$.

A curve is said to be equivalent to another curve if there exists a smooth bijection from the domain of the first curve to the domain of the second curve.

Comment: What is the domain of $t$?

Comment: Can you state precisely what your definition of "equivalent as curves" is?

Comment: I don't think your definition of equivalent curves is quite right, given that it doesn't do anything with the range.